# What are the possible usecases of empty select{}

Tags: go, concurrency, blocking, goroutine

I understand that the empty `select{}` blocks the go-Routine forever but fail to understand what all different use-cases does this cater to?

I also checked to go repo to find more usage, I could find only two implementations, one in [syscall/js](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.16.6:src/syscall/js/func.go;drc=828bb0c123af11d21c82eb87b64dfa9af24858c7;l=71)  and the other in [httptest](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.16.6:src/net/http/httptest/server.go;drc=5375c71289917ac7b25c6fa4bb0f4fa17be19a07;l=140).

```golang
func handleEvent() {
        cb := jsGo.Get("_pendingEvent")
        if cb.IsNull() {
                return
        }
        jsGo.Set("_pendingEvent", Null())

        id := uint32(cb.Get("id").Int())
        if id == 0 { // zero indicates deadlock
                select {}
        }
        funcsMu.Lock()
        f, ok := funcs[id]
        funcsMu.Unlock()
        if !ok {
                Global().Get("console").Call("error", "call to released function")
                return
        }

        this := cb.Get("this")
        argsObj := cb.Get("args")
        args := make([]Value, argsObj.Length())
        for i := range args {
                args[i] = argsObj.Index(i)
        }
        result := f(this, args)
        cb.Set("result", result)
}
```

Usage in httptest

```golang
// Start starts a server from NewUnstartedServer.
func (s *Server) Start() {
        if s.URL != "" {
                panic("Server already started")
        }
        if s.client == nil {
                s.client = &http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{}}
        }
        s.URL = "http://" + s.Listener.Addr().String()
        s.wrap()
        s.goServe()
        if serveFlag != "" {
                fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "httptest: serving on", s.URL)
                select {}
        }
}
```

The question here is how the `select {}` is used here and if there are any other usecases other than this, where we can leverage `select {}`?

Comment: It's more succinct than `<-make(chan bool)`

Answer (score 0):

`select {}` blocks the current goroutine forever.

A use-case is when you need to do that, obviously. This should be an exteremely rare situation.

The first example uses it to force a deadlock in the main goroutine, as eventID `0` is an impossibility.

But second example is a code smell.
You can almost always structure the code in a way that blocking a goroutine like that wouldn't be needed. For example, `s.goServe()` could be refactored into `s.serve()`, then it can be called in either blocking or non-blocking way, using `s.serve()` or `go s.serve()`, respectively.